# How can I run this custom AttentionLSTM class, built in TF 1.0, on TF 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm building upon the work of a colleague who built a custom AttentionLSTM layer in TF 1. I want to use TF 2.

I've changed all the import statements at the top to be `from tensorflow.keras import ...`. But there are two that I haven't figured out how to change.

```py
from keras.legacy import interfaces
from keras.layers import Recurrent
```

Both are used in the `AttentionLSTM` class definition once and no where else.

```py
class AttentionLSTM(Recurrent):

    @interfaces.legacy_recurrent_support
    def __init__(self, units,
                 activation='tanh',
                 recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
                 attention_activation='tanh',
                 use_bias=True,
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 recurrent_initializer='orthogonal',
                 attention_initializer='orthogonal',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 unit_forget_bias=True,
                 kernel_regularizer=None,
                 recurrent_regularizer=None,
                 bias_regularizer=None,
                 activity_regularizer=None,
                 attention_regularizer=None,
                 kernel_constraint=None,
                 recurrent_constraint=None,
                 bias_constraint=None,
                 attention_constraint=None,
                 dropout=0.,
                 recurrent_dropout=0.,
                 return_attention=False,
                 **kwargs):
        ...
```

What does the `interfaces` decorator do? What do I need to change so that I can use this class in TF 2?

Note: I think I should change the `Recurrent` import to `from tensorflow.keras.layers import RNN` but am worried that will mess up what the `interfaces` decorator does.

Answer (score 1):

`from keras.legacy import interfaces` and from `keras.layers import Recurrent` These two libraries work with Keras 2.3.1.
Latest Tensorflow version has default Keras 2.4.3 version.
In order to use these two libraries downgrade your Keras to 2.3.1.

Tensorflow.keras has no such library.

And for `keras.layers import Recurrent` use `tf.keras.layers.RNN`

Take a look at Keras release [note](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0).

Comment: Ahh ok thank you. Also, from [this link](https://docs.floydhub.com/guides/environments/) it seems like I can use a maximum of TF 2.2 with Keras 2.3.1. You cannot use just TF.